# Changelog from file

Tags: table-of-contents, tabu, revision-control

I'm trying to get a very nice changelog table in my template and I'm trying to do that using the table of contents way (so writing to a file and reading from that afterwards).
This works well, however it doesn't allow me (as far as I can see) to write these lines into a REAL table (so not a toc, but like a tabu or tabularx).

Anyone here who can help me with this?

Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tabu}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\l@changelogline[2]}{
    #2\\
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\changelog}{
    %\csname @starttoc\endcsname{cl}%
    \begin{tabu} spread \textwidth {l l l X[l]}
        \csname @starttoc\endcsname{cl}%    
    \end{tabu}
}
\addcontentsline{cl}{changelogline}{V0.1 & 21-02-2018 & Foitn & Initial version}
\addcontentsline{cl}{changelogline}{V0.2 & 22-02-2018 & Foitn & Some kind of change}
\begin{document}
    asdf
    \bigskip
    \changelog
\end{document}
```

Right now it's giving me this error:

```
Missing } inserted. ...18 & Foitn & Initial version}{1}{Doc-Start}
Missing \endgroup inserted. ...18 & Foitn & Initial version}{1}{Doc-Start}
```

Comment: The problem is, that `\@starttoc` starts with a `\begingroup` which wouldn't be ended in the cell of `tabu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the code I used to create the file. It doesn't write to the *.aux file, but directly to `\jobname.cl`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tabu}
\makeatletter
\newwrite\@changelog
\newcommand*\changelog@filename{\jobname.cl}
\newcommand*\changelog
  {%
    \IfFileExists{./\changelog@filename}
      {%
        \begin{tabu} spread \textwidth {l l l X[l]}%
          \input{\changelog@filename}
        \end{tabu}%
      }{}%
  }
\newcommand*\changelog@contents{}
\newcommand*\addchangelogline[4]
  {%
    \xdef\changelog@contents
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\changelog@contents
          #1 & #2 & #3 & #4\string\\
        }%
      }%
  }
\AtEndDocument
  {%
    \immediate\openout\@changelog=\changelog@filename
    \immediate\write\@changelog{\changelog@contents}%
    \immediate\closeout\@changelog
  }
\makeatother
\addchangelogline{v0.1}{21-02-2018}{Foitn}{Initial version}
\addchangelogline{v0.2}{22-02-2018}{Foitn}{Some kind of change}
\begin{document}
  asdf
  \bigskip
  \changelog
\end{document}
```

Working way of using `\addtocontents` and the like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tabu}
\makeatletter
\newwrite\@changelog
\newcommand*\changelog@extension{cl}
\newcommand*\changelog@filename{}
\edef\changelog@filename{\jobname.\changelog@extension}
\newcommand*\changelog
  {%
    \IfFileExists{./\changelog@filename}
      {%
        \begin{tabu} spread \textwidth {l l l X[l]}%
          \input{\changelog@filename}
        \end{tabu}%
      }{}%
      \bgroup
      \renewcommand*\changelogline[4]{}%
      \@starttoc{\changelog@extension}%
      \egroup
  }
\newcommand*\changelog@contents{}
\newcommand*\changelogline[4]{#1 & #2 & #3 & #4\\}
\newcommand*\addchangelogline[4]
  {%
    \addtocontents{\changelog@extension}
      {\protect\changelogline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
  }
%\show\@starttoc
\makeatother
\addchangelogline{v0.1}{21-02-2018}{Foitn}{Initial version}
\addchangelogline{v0.2}{22-02-2018}{Foitn}{Some kind of change}
\begin{document}
  asdf
  \bigskip
  \changelog
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks very good! Thank you for the effort! Though, the addtocontents doesn't seem to work. After a little googling I found that this command only works for toc, lot & lof. I'll keep searching to write to a different file

Comment: the file is not created on my pc :(

Comment: @Foitn Guess that's my fault, I did create it with a different code beforehand and didn't delete it in between.

Comment: wow, this works like a charm, thank you so much!